How could tusked dragons eat?
The tusked dragon is a roughly reptilian/dinosaurian carnivore which possesses a large tusk-like horn on the nose which points directly forwards. They are bipeds like dinosaurs and have a flexible avian neck. Their hands are not able to grasp


All examples I have found of similar tusks/nose-horns are either fairly small or don't point directly down the snout. The only exception I could find are elephants, which have a trunk to feed themselves: This won't work for the tusked dragon as it lacks a trunk
How could this tusked dragon get its food into its mouth with its forward-pointing tusk in the way?

y Ddraig Goch ;)

if they have long flexible necks they can just turn the head sideways to bite, they just are not hunting with their mouths.

There's a couple options here! First, a prehensile tail could be an excellent gripping "tool" akin to an elephant's trunk in this function. Second, some creative head turning and pinning with the claws (which, despite being unable to grip, ostensibly have quite a lot of weight with which to secure prey). The others I can think of have already been mentioned-- kudos to the other responses!

 Dear Ichthys King,
I'm so tired of the rampant speculation about this. I'm going to set the record straight once and for all.
No, I do not use the horn to skewer princesses and dig them out of their castles. I've been fairly vocal about this.
When I eat, I eat white dragons. When I do, I do it like any self respecting Welshmen would do it. With a knife and fork.
Very respectfully,
Y Ddraig Goch
Anorchfygol Ddraig Cymru

On the internet, nobody knows you're a dragon.

This is the best answer. And if you don't know why, Wales is a lovely place.

@TheDemonLord Cymru am byth

Like a shark
That profile looks a little like that of a shark, and a lot like that of a goblin shark specifically.
Sharks have flexible jaws made of cartilage, and often eat things small enough compared to them that they can fit inside of their jaws (or at least fit enough for one lethal bite). Perhaps these dragons have cartilage jaws/other bones as well. Alternatively, they may have disconnected jaw bones like those of a snake, allowing for a similar stretching and reshaping.
Goblin sharks take this to the extreme, with more complex jaws that retract and expand notably more than those of other sharks. While that doesn't seem to be related to their nose length (though they do sometimes use their nose to ram fish and stun them), the long face protrusion at the very least isn't interfering too much.
The tusks of these dragons may actually help them eat, providing a handy lever for tearing away their bite.

I suspect you are confusing the feeding habits of the goblin shark (Mitsukurina owstoni) with those of the cookie cutter shark (Isistius brailiensis).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goblin_shark    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookiecutter_shark

You are absolutely right, will edit when I get time

There we go, fixed.

You dragon can have prehensile lips, like among others lake sturgeon, orangutans, horses, and rhinos.
In particular the lake sturgeon closely resembles the aspect of your dragon, so they can feed in the same way. (image source)


If they have long tongues, like Chamaleons, and a mouth with enough strength and size, they could use it to bring the food (dead or alive) to its mouth. Possibly, the tongue could have a type of glue or some small "teeth" in it, to prevent the pray to leave.
Of course this would limit the thing it can eat, must be always something not so big. Or it could toast the food before eat, making it easier to split into pieces with its tongue.

Like a spider- with a set of feeding tusk- injecting a solution. Food is the goop the victim is dissolved into. If you want coolness factor, add those to the mouth- and it looks like the victim is slurped up at speed.
